# Java MongoTemplate exclude child relations in query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

**Background:**

I'm using Spring-boot and MongoDB.

```
public class User {
   @DBRef
   private List<Contact> contacts;
   ...


public class Contact {

   @DBRef
   private List<Booking> bookings;
   ...

   public Contact(){}

   public Contact(Booking booking){
       this.bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
       this.bookings.add(booking);
       ...
   }

@Override
public List<Contact> findAllContactsForUser(String id) {
    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria
            .where("_id").is(id));
    query.fields().include("contacts");
    User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class);
    return user.getContacts();
}
```

Output from findAllContactsForUser:

```
[
   {
     "field":"value",
     "bookings": [
                   "field":"value"
                 ]
   }
]
```

**Problem:**

The result I want:

```
[
   {
     "field":"value",
     "bookings": null
   }
]
```

How do I exclude the bookings relationship from my query in findAllContactsForUser?

Comment: I see the new ArrayList in your Contact's constructor. I see no evidence it is being called yet, but I suspect it is. Can you add the code for User too (setContacts, getContacts +  constructors) + Contact 's setBookings, getBookings

Answer (score 1):

You just need to exclude the field `contacts.bookings` in your query:

```
@Override
public List<Contact> findAllContactsForUser(String id) {
    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
    query.fields().exclude("contacts.bookings");
    User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class);
    return user.getContacts();
}
```

By the way, no need for the `.include(contacts)`, fields are included by default.

Comment: That just gives me an empty array = [ ].

Comment: I tested with your model and it works for me. Can you post the complete code for your Contact class ?

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your code where you do "new ArrayList()" for bookings ?

Comment: Just updated my question with som code from Contact.class